# K9 doesn't like my SSL cert

Tags: certificates, k9-mail

My mail provider recently updated their SSL certificate and now I'm getting errors in K9 mail when I try to test my server information:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0407006A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:block type is not 01 (SHA-1))`

Is this a problem with their certificate? It works fine in Thunderbird. Or is the problem with K9 mail?

Comment: It's hard to tell if it's a bug in K9 or Android's SSL handling itself, but it looks like it was [reported and discussed on K9's issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/k9mail/issues/detail?id=3976). The last comment references a GitHub pull request that doesn't appear to have been merged into the main codebase, though. The ticket's about a year old, so I don't know if it just got abandoned or what.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out whether Dreamhost could solve this by fixing their SSL certificate.

Comment: I'm not really sure either. The discussion seems to imply that the error is caused by certificate chains that have a self-signed cert in the middle of the chain, and OpenSSL is more tolerant of this than Android's SSL implementation (which might be why Thunderbird works).